# Reinstall smb / samba

Tags: linux, ubuntu, samba, server-message-block

Is there a way to reinstall smb & samba as if it was a clean install?

I am having so much problems with accessing Windows Share directories on my Ubuntu 11.10 (with Gnome 3 Shell) that I want to try reinstalling this subsystem entirely.

I've tried AskUbuntu with this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74789/failed-to-retrieve-share-list-from-server-error-when-browsing-a-share-with-nau) and this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74838/how-do-i-completely-remove-samba) to no avail.

Please help.

NOTE: I can't "mount" nor browse (using Nautilus).

Answer (score 3):

```
apt-get --purge remove samba
apt-get clean
apt-get install samba
```

Comment: And put `sudo` before each command to gain the access rights.